# Running Tensorflow Classifier Model in C++/Obj-C++ results in different result than Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, machine-learning, tensorflow

Ive retrained an InceptionV3 model via the [Tensorflow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/) tutorials and can successfully run label_image.py on my trained data and on new data and get correct labels with good accuracy. Awesome!

If I run my model through my Mac Obj-C++ app my resulting labels are wildly different.

For example - my training is to classify which 'shot type' a frame of video is, (extreme close up, close up, medium, long, extreme long) for classifying video editing content.

label_image.py classifies a frame from a video as 85% likely close up. 
My C++ / Obj-C App run with the same frame classifies it as Extreme Long with 60%

Both are running the same version of Tensorflow (1.1) on Mac OS X CPU compiled with AVX/SIMD/FMA optimizations.

My Apps pipeline :

I have a BGR ordered OpenCV Mat image which I can use successfully elsewhere and get sane results from. I create this CV Mat from an OS X CVPixelBufferRef mapped to a BGRA CV MAT like so:

```
cv::cvtColor(BGRAImage, frameMat, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```

I feed that BGR CV Mat (named frameMat) into a Tensor via code borrowed from the iOS contrib example, like so :

```
 void* baseAddress = (void*)frameMat.datastart;
 size_t width = (size_t) frameMat.cols;
 size_t height = (size_t) frameMat.rows;
 size_t bytesPerRow =  (size_t) frameMat.cols * 3; // (BGR)

 const int wanted_input_width = 299;
 const int wanted_input_height = 299;
 const int wanted_input_channels = 3;
 const float input_mean = 128.0f;
 const float input_std = 128.0f;

 resized_tensor = tensorflow::Tensor( tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({1, wanted_input_height, wanted_input_width, wanted_input_channels}));

auto image_tensor_mapped = resized_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();
tensorflow::uint8 *in = sourceStartAddr;
float *out = image_tensor_mapped.data();
for (int y = 0; y < wanted_input_height; ++y)
{
    float *out_row = out + (y * wanted_input_width * wanted_input_channels);
    for (int x = 0; x < wanted_input_width; ++x)
    {
        const int in_x = (y * (int)width) / wanted_input_width;
        const int in_y = (x * image_height) / wanted_input_height;

        tensorflow::uint8 *in_pixel = in + (in_y * width * (image_channels)) + (in_x * (image_channels));
        float *out_pixel = out_row + (x * wanted_input_channels);

        // Interestingly the iOS example uses BGRA and DOES NOT re-order tensor channels to RGB <-> BGR
        // Matching that.
        out_pixel[0] = ((float)in_pixel[0] - (float)input_mean) / (float)input_std;
        out_pixel[1] = ((float)in_pixel[1] - (float)input_mean) / (float)input_std;
        out_pixel[2] = ((float)in_pixel[2] - (float)input_mean) / (float)input_std;
    }
}
```

My session creation code:

```
 tensorflow::Status load_graph_status = ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), [inception2015GraphPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &inceptionGraphDef);

 if (load_graph_status.ok())
 {      
      tensorflow::SessionOptions options;        
      inceptionSession = std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>(tensorflow::NewSession(options));        
      tensorflow::Status session_create_status = inceptionSession->Create(inceptionGraphDef);
 }
```

Running the graph:

```
    tensorflow::Status run_status = inceptionSession->Run({ {input_layer, resized_tensor} }, {feature_layer, final_layer}, {}, &outputs);
```

And pulling out the labels / feature vector (penultimate layer)

```
    NSMutableArray* outputLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.labelsArray.count];
NSMutableArray* outputScores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.labelsArray.count];

// 1 = labels and scores
auto predictions = outputs[1].flat<float>();

for (int index = 0; index < predictions.size(); index += 1)
{
    const float predictionValue = predictions(index);

    NSString* labelKey  = self.labelsArray[index % predictions.size()];

    NSNumber* currentLabelScore = self.averageLabelScores[labelKey];

    NSNumber* incrementedScore = @([currentLabelScore floatValue] + predictionValue );
    self.averageLabelScores[labelKey] = incrementedScore;

    [outputLabels addObject:labelKey];
    [outputScores addObject:@(predictionValue)];
}

// 0 is feature vector
tensorflow::Tensor feature = outputs[0];
int64_t numElements = feature.NumElements();
tensorflow::TTypes<float>::Flat featureVec = feature.flat<float>();

NSMutableArray* featureElements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numElements];

for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
{
    [featureElements addObject:@( featureVec(i) ) ];
}

if(self.averageFeatureVec == nil)
{
    self.averageFeatureVec = featureElements;
}
else
{
    // average each vector element with the prior
    for(int i = 0; i < featureElements.count; i++)
    {
        float  a = [featureElements[i] floatValue];
        float  b = [self.averageFeatureVec[i] floatValue];

        self.averageFeatureVec[i] = @( MAX(a,b)) ;
    }
}

return @{ kSynopsisStandardMetadataFeatureVectorDictKey : featureElements ,
          @"Labels" : outputLabels,
          @"Scores" : outputScores,
          };
```

I've attempted to look into the tensor ordering (NHWC), and have checked the tensor creation code but I might be missing something obvious to others. Ive also tried changing channel order, to no avail.

Any insight would be greatly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this one is tricky.

I failed to mention I was running the graph_transform tool on my retrained graph - and was running quantize weights to lower my graphs size. In the past, I've not had an issue with this messing up classification scores at all, but apparently that caused an issue.

Running the above code with a graph transform call without quantize weights fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My usual method for debugging issues like this is:

- First save out a raw C array of values from an example input that I know works. For example, make sure that label_image works with your newly-trained model, and then write out the float* array you get from `input_layer->flat<float>().data()`, using pseudo-code like this:

`float* input_data = input_layer->flat<float>().data();
    int input_data_count = input_layer->flat<float>().size();
    printf("float g_test_input[]={\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < input_data_count; ++i) {
      printf("  %f,\n", input_data[i]);
    }
    printf("};\n");`

- You should end up with a big array that you can copy into your new code. Overwrite whatever input you have in the code you want to test. Now run it, and you should see the same output that you saw from label_image. If you don't, you know there's something different about the model you're loading. If the output is identical, then you know that the input preprocessing is different.
- Assuming that it's the preprocessing that's wrong, my next step is to try loading an image from disk. The iOS example code does that in the simple example. Save out some of your expected input into an image file, and then make sure that both label_image and your code produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks Pete - 

I failed to mention (I didn't think it pertinent) that I ran the graph from retrain.py through the graph_transform tool, with these args:

bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph --in_graph="in.pb" --out_graph="out.pb" --inputs='Mul' --outputs='pool_3, final_result' --transforms='strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,229,229,3") remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics) fold_constants(ignore_errors=true) fold_batch_norms fold_old_batch_norms quantize_weights sort_by_execution_order fuse_resize_pad_and_conv' 

removing quantize_weights fixes it.